# Floating action button size changed automatically in different places

Tags: android

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/btnFAB"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:elevation="6dp"
   app:fabSize="normal"
   app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp" />
```

This is my FAB button XML, and I'm using it this way:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/empty_layout_qms"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qms_empty_view_image"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:srcCompat ="@drawable/zero_query"
        />

    <com.snapdeal.uimodule.views.SourceSansTextView
        android:id="@+id/qms_zero_state_textView_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/zero_state_text_margin_top"
        app:typeface="source_sans_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/qms_zero_state_text_header"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_dark_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/zero_state_header_font_size" />

    <com.snapdeal.uimodule.views.SourceSansTextView
        android:id="@+id/qms_zero_state_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/zero_state_text_margin_top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/qms_zero_state_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/color_lablel_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/zero_state_content_font_size" />
    <com.snapdeal.uimodule.views.SourceSansButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
        android:textSize="@dimen/zero_state_content_font_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/zero_state_text_margin_disc"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fourty"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/fourty"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/zero_try_again"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/tv_zero_state_qms_action"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qms_zero_state_textView"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/temp_fab_view"

        >
        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/fab_view_stub_temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/zero_state_fab_layout" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/zero_disc"
            android:text="Create Query"
            android:elevation="7dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[This is how it is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4khpS.png) , [But i want it this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqTA2.png). It was working fine, but now FAB is changing its size some where it is normal, and in some place it's looking like a full stop.

Comment: why don't give you FAB height and width exactly dimension.

Comment: just use it <dimen name="design_fab_image_size">36dp</dimen> and give this size to your width and height

Comment: and also android:scaleType="center"

Comment: I gave the fixed size, even then its not working

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your `RelativeLayout` does not have enough room to inflate the `FloatingActionButton` properly. How big is the parent view of that `RelativeLayout`?